# Connecting to DB (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa

Good afternoon, I am currently working on connecting to the DB using JPA, but while I am trying to connect few errors showed up, which I don`t understand to be honest.

Main idea of my code is to connect on local DB using Entity manager and to select all info from DB, then to lower price (cena) of books (kniha) by 10 percent and to commit all the changes to the DB.

By the way I know that name of book (nazov) is not properly good for primary key, but in this situation I am just testing and trying out what JPA can do.

Main program:

```
package cviko2;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author vsa
 */
public class Cviko2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("p1app2PU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from KNIHA", Kniha.class);
        List<Kniha> r = (List<Kniha>) q.getResultList();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        for(Kniha k: r){
            k.setCena((float) (k.getCena() * 0.9));
        }

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

Kniha class:

```
package cviko2;

import java.io.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 *
 * @author vsa
 */
@Entity
public class Kniha implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String nazov;
    private float cena;

    public Kniha(String nazov, float cena) {
        this.nazov = nazov;
        this.cena = cena;
    }

    public float getCena() {
        return cena;
    }

    public void setCena(float cena) {
        this.cena = cena;
    }

    public String getNazov() {
        return nazov;
    }

    public void setNazov(String nazov) {
        this.nazov = nazov;
    }
}
```

And finally errors -.-

```
[EL Info]: 2019-03-03 17:18:26.674--ServerSession(22429093)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2019-03-03 17:18:26.897--ServerSession(22429093)--file:/home/vsa/NetBeansProjects/Cviko2/build/classes/_p1app2PU login successful
[EL Warning]: metamodel: 2019-03-03 17:18:26.92--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
[EL Warning]: 2019-03-03 17:18:27.005--UnitOfWork(393040818)--Exception [EclipseLink-6007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class cviko2.Kniha].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Kniha sql="select * from KNIHA")
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class cviko2.Kniha].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Kniha sql="select * from KNIHA")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:480)
    at cviko2.Cviko2.main(Cviko2.java:26)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class cviko2.Kniha].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Kniha sql="select * from KNIHA")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.descriptorIsMissing(QueryException.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkDescriptor(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
    ... 1 more
/home/vsa/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Define your model classes in persistence.xml. You can examine this link for example https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa/java-persistence-xml-example/

Comment: What's the table name?

Comment: Why use SQL when you can use JPQL and be independent of SQL ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Entity class must have a public or protected, no-argument constructor.
>   The class may have other constructors.

If you create constructor with arguments there is no default no-args constructor. Add no-args constructor to entity.